# Elegant way for multiple for in?

Tags: python

What is the elegant way in python for this kind of case ?

```
products_names = ''
for movement in movements:
  for product in movement.products:
    products_names += product.name + ', '
```

Comment: I think what you've written is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work fine:

```
products_names = ', '.join([product.name for movement in movements for product in movement.products])
```

The list comprehension, creates a list of `product.name` for all the products. And then we [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the list on `', '` to get the final string.

You can also avoid creating the list alltogether, by using a generator expression:

```
products_names = ', '.join(product.name for movement in movements for product in movement.products)
```

Note that, with `join()`, list comprehension gives better result than generator expression.

Comment: Note that a list comprehension is more efficient with the `join` method.

Answer (score 3):

```
product_names = ", ".join([product.name for movement in movements for product in movement.products])
```

This solution takes advantage of the [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method of a string as well as a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Note also that I used a comprehension rather than a generator expression.  This is because, while generators are *usually* faster than comprehensions, the `join` method actually works better with a comprehension.  See this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python/9061024#9061024).

Answer (score 3):

Using `map` and an anonymous function may make it more readable in this case; it's debatable.

```
", ".join(map(lambda x: ", ".join(x.products), movements))
```

`reduce` could also be used but is probably less readable than the comprehensions:

```
reduce(lambda y,z: y + ", " + z, map(lambda x: ", ".join(x.products), movements))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten some of the above examples slightly by using `chain`, which is great for flattening lists of lists:

```
 from itertools import chain

 product_names = ', '.join([x.name for x in chain(*movements)])
```

Assuming that `movements` == `[l1, l2, l3, ...]` and for each `l`, they look like `[p1, p2, p3, p4, ...]`, then this is what it does:

```
 chain(*movements)
```

This does one level of flattening on movement. The * rolls out movements into the chain function - i.e. this is effectively the same as calling `chain(l1, l2, l3)`.

```
 [x.name for x in chain(*movements)]
```

But we actually want some processing on each item, so add a list comprehension to pull the value out we want instead.

note that the list comprehension is still faster, because of join.
without doing lookups, i got the following results:

```
 tl  = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
 %timeit ','.join(chain(*tl))
 100000 loops, best of 3: 1.78 us per loop
 %timeit ','.join([x for l in tl for x in l])
 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 us per loop
 %timeit ','.join([x for x in chain(*tl)])
 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 us per loop
```